# Building a linear model from scratch

Tags: python, classification

I would like to build a linear model to predict the class of instances. The classes are of element `{-1, 1}`. For that I would like to [minimize the empirical risk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_risk_minimization).

My code seems to work, since it outputs an array, with the size of the number of features of an input element x, with each attribute being of element `{-1, 1}`. Now I would like to know **how to proceed**. Do I just have to build the dot product and check, if it is negative or positive?

**Example:**

One input element, with 5 features:

```
[1, 1, -1, -1, -1]
```

The model:

```
[7, 5, -2, 0, 3]
```

Build dot product of model and input x:

```
7 + 5 + 2 + 0 - 3 = 11
```

result:

```
11 > 0, x should be of class 1
```

**addition:**

The code to build the model

```
def learn_reg_ERM(X,y,lbda):
    # define consts
    max_iter = 200
    e  = 0.001
    alpha = 1.

    # init model
    w = np.random.randn(X.shape[1]);
    for k in np.arange(max_iter):
        # dot product/scalar product
        # [a, b, c] * [d, e, f] = [ad, be, cf]
        h = np.dot(X,w)
        # calculate (and print) loss and gradient of loss
        l,lg = loss(h, y)
        # print 'loss: {}'.format(np.mean(l))
        # calculate regularizers and gradient of regularizer at point w
        r,rg = reg(w, lbda)
        # calc loss + regularizer 
        g = np.dot(X.T,lg) + rg 

        if (k > 0):
            # update alpha
            alpha = alpha * (np.dot(g_old.T,g_old))/(np.dot((g_old - g).T,g_old))
        w = w - alpha * g
        # check if minimum is found
        if (np.linalg.norm(alpha * g) < e):
            break
        g_old = g
    return w
```

Comment: Please add more details. You want to do linear classification? Show what your code does for now, and indicate exactly what you need an answer for

Comment: Linear models are not an adequate choice here. You are using a regression model to do a classification. This makes no sense, as any number between -1 and 1 cannot be interpreted. You should definitively use a classification algorithm for that. A simple `Nearest Neighbor` approach will do.
What is that you label "The Model"? Are these slopes for each feature?

Comment: @HitLuca I will add more comments

Comment: @offeltoffel I am using a classifier, not regression. I am sorry, if my description was confusing on that.